# Is it possible to check whether a "experimental feature" in Safari is active?

Tags: safari, webgl

I precisely require this for the `WebGL 2.0` as well as `WebGL via Metal` experimental features. Is it possible to check whether they're active via some API call?

Comment: For `webgl2` you can just try to get a context I suppose?

Comment: Good idea, thanks! I'm still wondering whether it's possible to _generally_ check, whether these features are on or off.